# SQL to update part of data field

Tags: sql-server

I am looking to put an SQL update statement together to remove an ampersand sign (&) for customer names - I need to replace it with the word 'and'.

This will be for multiple customer records.

Thanks
Paula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing a bit more about the data structure and which server you're using it is difficult to suggest an answer.  If you're using Microsoft's SQL Server, you can look at using the [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.  For example

```
UPDATE Customers
SET CustomerName = REPLACE(CustomerName, ' & ', ' and ')
```

I created a quick demo for you in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e328a/2).

Comment: Thanks Mark - I need the code to make the changes to update the '&' to the actual word 'and' in the customer names as it is causing things to fail (the software it is running on uses the ampersand as a special sign).  I will do a select 1st to see how many customers are affected but suspect there could be 100's if not over 1000.  Thanks for all your guidance & sorry that I was vague in my question - it was the 1st time I had ever posted one, so didn't know how much level of detail to go into - thought if someone could help, they would have then asked for more detail.

Comment: @user188667, I hope my answer got you started on the right path!  Feel free to edit your question as you learn more if you need additional clarity.